# Detecting the Appearance of a Path between a Pair of Vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Given

- a simple, symmetric graph $G(V,E); \text{card}(V)=n,\ \text{card}(E)=m\le\frac{n(n-1)}{2} $
- a set of ordered pairs of vertices $U=\lbrace (u_i,u_j)\rbrace\subset V\times V,\ i\lt j$
- a permutation of $\pi(E)$ that resembles an ordering of the edges

> **Question:**
>
> how fast can the appearance of a path between the vertices of *any* $(u_i,u_j)\in U$ be detected, if the edges of $G$ are inserted one by one in the order defined by $\pi(E)$ into a graph $H$, that initially only contains the set $V$ of vertices of $G$?

Answers stating the conditions, under which a specific algorithm will be fast(est) would be a great help in testing a (probably new) TSP heuristic.

Comment: I imagine time roughly quadratic in the number of vertices.  Start by assigning a different number to each vertex.  When an edge is added, if it joins two vertices with different numbers, reassign the smaller number to all vertices with the higher number, otherwise leave things alone. You are maintaining an equivalence relation of connected components.  Gerhard "Not Sure Where This Leads" Paseman, 2018.02.03.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I was thinking, that maybe an adaptation of the [disjoint set union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) algorithm may yield faster algorithms. But I think that problem should have already appeared elsewhere.